# Mandar un mensaje con Swiftmailer desde un comando Symfony

Tags: php, symfony2

mi problema es que estoy intentando mandar un mensaje desde un command en Symfony 2 pero es todo errores, este es mi código:

```
$message = $this->mailer
        ->setFrom('from@example.com')
        ->setTo('example@tt.com')
        ->setSubject('Subject')
        ->setBody('Body')
        ->attach($xml)
    ;

    $this->mailer()->send($message);
```

La clase del comando extiende del AbstractCommand que a su vez extiende del ContainerAwareCommand, y el abstractCommand tiene una función para coger los containers, y en ella tengo lo siguiente:

```
$this->mailer = $this->getContainer()->get('mailer');
```

Y este es el error que me da al ejecutar mi comando

> Notice: Undefined property: Project\Libraries\ReportsBundle\Command\GenerateXMLCommand::$mailer

Me gustaría a poder ser que me dijeran una manera de mandar mensajes desde un comando de Symfony 2.

Un saludo. Gracias.

Comment: Cuál es la versión de Symfony2 que usas?

Comment: @h40s4m4 la versión de symfony que uso es la 2.0

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class GreetCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        //Blah Blah configuración
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $mailer = $this->getContainer()->get('mailer');

        $message = $mailer
          ->setFrom('from@example.com')
          ->setTo('example@tt.com')
          ->setSubject('Subject')
          ->setBody('Body')
          //No se de donde viene este $xml, pero ahí lo dejo según tu código
          ->attach($xml)
          ;

         $mailer->send($message);
    }
}
```

Posiblemente no estás instanciando en tu clase correctamente el objeto `mailer` del `container` (intentas llamar a $this->mailer, esto sólo puedes hacerlo si los instanciaste/seteaste previamente). El ejemplo que te dejo es un pequeño mod de la documentación de Symfony2 para la versión 2.0

Nota: La versión 2.0 está muy Deprecated, deberías darle upgrade a tu versión al menos hasta la 2.4

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/console/console_command.html